# How to Add iOS application in sharing options in Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

**Basically, what I want :-**

To allow user to share url from Chrome/Safari/Other's application in my application. I have searched regarding this functionality but couldn't get any working solution for iOS.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far ? Which one is not working on iOS ?